# Problema con include de EntityFramework Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estoy desarrollando una Web Api con ASP.Net core pero tengo un problema con el EF Core. Resulta que tengo una BBDD SQL server pero no es relacional (Con esto quiero decir que no tengo las tablas relacionadas entre si en la Base de datos) y al hacer `include()` en una una de las tablas.

### Para resumir

Tengo una tabla cabecera y otra de Líneas. En el controlador cuando hago la consulta a la base de datos, me trae correctamente los datos de la cabecera pero los datos de las líneas no.

A continuación muestro como lo tengo configurado.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CabeceraPedidoProveedor> GetOrdenes()
    {
        var ret = _ctx.CabeceraPedidoProveedor.Where(x=>x.SeriePedido == "F")
                     .Include(e=> e.LineasPedidoProveedor).ToList();
        return ret;
                 
    }
```

/Modelo CabeceraPedidoProveedor.cs

```
     public partial class CabeceraPedidoProveedor
     {
 
         public CabeceraPedidoProveedor()
         {
             LineasPedidoProveedor = new HashSet<LineasPedidoProveedor>();
         }
 
         public Guid IdPedidoPro { get; set; }
         public short CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
         public short EjercicioPedido { get; set; }
         public string SeriePedido { get; set; }
         public int NumeroPedido { get; set; }
         public DateTime FechaPedido { get; set; }
         public short NumeroLineas { get; set; }
         public string CodigoProveedor { get; set; }
         public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
 
         public virtual Enumerable<LineasPedidoProveedor>LineasPedidoProveedor     { get; set; } }
```

/Modelo LineasPedidoProveedor.cs

```
     public partial class LineasPedidoProveedor
     {
 
         public short CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
         public short EjercicioPedido { get; set; }
         public string SeriePedido { get; set; }
         public int NumeroPedido { get; set; }
          
         //public short CodigoEmpresaCabecera { get; set; }
         //public short EjercicioPedidoCabecera { get; set; }
         //public string SeriePedidoCabecera { get; set; }
         //public short NumeroPedidoCabecera { get; set; }
         public short Orden { get; set; }
         public Guid LineasPosicion { get; set; }
 
         public virtual CabeceraPedidoProveedor Cabecera { get; set; }}

//Contexto

    public partial class MiContext : DbContext
        {
    
            public MiContext (DbContextOptions options
              ):base(options)
            {
    
            }
    
            public virtual DbSet<CabeceraPedidoProveedor> CabeceraPedidoProveedor { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<LineasPedidoProveedor> LineasPedidoProveedor { get; set; }
                    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
                  modelBuilder.Entity<CabeceraPedidoProveedor>(entity =>
                  {
                    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CodigoEmpresa, e.EjercicioPedido, e.SeriePedido, e.NumeroPedido });
    
                    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CodigoEmpresa,e.EjercicioPedido,e.SeriePedido,e.NumeroPedido})
                        .HasName("CabeceraPedidoProveedor_Pedido");
    
                    entity.ToTable("CabeceraPedidoProveedor");
    
                      entity.Property(e => e.CodigoEmpresa).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                      entity.Property(e => e.EjercicioPedido).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                      entity.Property(e => e.SeriePedido)
                        .HasMaxLength(10)
                        .IsUnicode(false)
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("('')");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.NumeroPedido)
                          .HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.NumeroLineas).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.FechaPedido)
                          .HasColumnType("datatime")
                          .HasDefaultValueSql("(getDate())");
    
                    //entity.HasMany(e => e.LineasPedido);
    
                    entity.HasMany(e => e.LineasPedidoProveedor)
                          .WithOne(e => e.Cabecera).HasConstraintName("FK_Lineas_Cabecera");
                          //.HasForeignKey(e=>new { e.CodigoEmpresa, e.EjercicioPedido, e.SeriePedido, e.NumeroPedido });
                  });
    
                  modelBuilder.Entity<LineasPedidoProveedor>(entity=>
                  {
    
                    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CodigoEmpresa, e.EjercicioPedido, e.SeriePedido, e.NumeroPedido, e.Orden,e.LineasPosicion });
    
                    //entity.HasIndex(e => new {e.CodigoEmpresa,e.EjercicioPedido,e.SeriePedido,e.NumeroPedido,e.Orden,e.LineasPosicion })
                    //      .HasName("LineasPedidoProveedor_Pedido");
    
                    entity.ToTable("LineasPedidoProveedor");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.CodigoEmpresa).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.EjercicioPedido).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.SeriePedido)
                          .HasMaxLength(10)
                          .HasDefaultValueSql("('')");
                    entity.Property(e => e.NumeroPedido).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
    
                    entity.HasOne(d => d.Cabecera)
                       .WithMany(p => p.LineasPedidoProveedor);
    
                  });
            }
```

Mi salida es esta:

```
[{"idPedidoPro":"18a351a6-c228-401c-b90c-dd9eb66278f9","codigoEmpresa":9999,"ejercicioPedido":2017,"seriePedido":"F","numeroPedido":108,"fechaPedido":"2017-09-14T00:00:00","numeroLineas":4,"codigoProveedor":"000000","razonSocial":"PROVEED VARIOS","lineasPedidoProveedor":[]}]
```

Como se puede ver, los datos de la tabla padre (la cabecera) los trae bien, pero *LineasPEdidoProveedor* viene en blanco. Me he asegurado de que tenga datos.

No se por donde meterle mano a esto.
Espero su ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Lo unico que veo es que estas definiendo las relaciones en las dos entidades y no estoy seguro de que impacto pueda tener eso, te recomendaría dejar una sola : HasMany en cabecera o HasOne en lineas. Te recomiendo esta documentacion : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: Gracias Mauricio. Eso tambien lo probè, y nada... no hay manera de que saque los datos....

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando

```
var ret = _ctx.CabeceraPedidoProveedor
                .Include(e=> e.LineasPedidoProveedor)
                .Where(x=>x.SeriePedido == "F")
                .ToList();
```

o sea siempre primero el `Include()`

Lo planteo porque siempre vi el uso de este metodo se define al comienzo

[Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: Gracias Leandro, lo he cambiado pero sigue igual.... Tiene algo que ver que en la base de datos no tenga diseñada ningún diagrama de relaciones?

Comment: no eso no afecta a linq si mapeas las relaciones en las entidades, pero debes definir como se relacionan en el mapping que relalizas en el contexto de EF

Comment: Gracias Leandro. La verdad es que tengo un "problema" con el tema de mapear (Y lo mismo vienen por hay los tiros). Lo explico. Tenemos instalado un ERP con Base de Datos SQL Server y las tablas ya creadas, aunque tengo la posibilidad de modificar las tablas no es recomendable. El problema que veo es que por ejemplo, las tablas Cabecera y Lineas tienen como claves los mismos campos y se llaman igual... Por ejemplo, en las dos tablas hay dos campos que se llaman SeriePedido y NumeroPedido y en las dos son campos claves...

Comment: Una alternativa, si no puedes modificar la estructura de las tablas, sería crear vistas en SQL. En la vista puedes crear consultas enlazando tablas aunque no estén relacionadas, y cambiando el nombre de los campos si tienes campos con el mismo nombre.

Answer (score 0):

He revisado su codigo y solo algunas cosas me llaman la atencion. Por ejemplo el uso de Enumerable en vez IEnumerable. Aunque en estos casos casi siempre uso ICOllection porque permite manipular la lista(agregar, eliminar, o modificar).

Ejemplo:

```
public partial class CabeceraPedidoProveedor
 {

 public CabeceraPedidoProveedor()
 {
     LineasPedidoProveedor = new HashSet<LineasPedidoProveedor>();
 }

 public Guid IdPedidoPro { get; set; }
 public short CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
 public short EjercicioPedido { get; set; }
 public string SeriePedido { get; set; }
 public int NumeroPedido { get; set; }
 public DateTime FechaPedido { get; set; }
 public short NumeroLineas { get; set; }
 public string CodigoProveedor { get; set; }
 public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<LineasPedidoProveedor>LineasPedidoProveedor 
...
```

La segunda clase necesita definir the ForeignKey:

```
public partial class LineasPedidoProveedor {

     public short CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
     public short EjercicioPedido { get; set; }
     public string SeriePedido { get; set; }
     public int NumeroPedido { get; set; }
// LLave foranea al Tabla CabeceraProveedor
     public int CabeceraPedidoProveedorId { get; set; }
     public short Orden { get; set; }
     public Guid LineasPosicion { get; set; }

     public virtual CabeceraPedidoProveedor Cabecera { get; set; }
}
```

por ultimo usando FluentApi definimos la relacion 1 a muchos en la clase que tiene la referencia al 1.

```
//Eliminar esto
                entity.HasMany(e => e.LineasPedidoProveedor)
                      .WithOne(e => e.Cabecera).HasConstraintName("FK_Lineas_Cabecera");
                      //.HasForeignKey(e=>new { e.CodigoEmpresa, e.EjercicioPedido, e.SeriePedido, e.NumeroPedido });
              });
```

usar esto:

```
...
modelBuilder.Entity<LineasPedidoProveedor>(entity=>
              {
...
  entity.HasRequired<CabeceraPedidoProveedor>(b => b.Cabecera)
        .WithMany(a => a.LineasPedidoProveedor)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(b => b.CabeceraPedidoProveedorId);
...
}
```

Ahora cuado use la recomendacion de la otra respuesta debe obtener la lista de elementos.

```
var ret = _ctx.CabeceraPedidoProveedor
            .Include(e=> e.LineasPedidoProveedor)
            .Where(x=>x.SeriePedido == "F")
            .ToList();
```

Espero esta solucion le ayude con su problema